# How do I retrieve this link with python selenium from a webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriver

How do I retrieve the youtube link from this row?

```
<input class="copy-input-text" readonly="" value="http://youtube.com">
```

Thought I would be able to retrieve it with find_element_by_xpath("") and copy pasting the xpath link. But I dont get the value printed out.

Can someone help

Comment: _Thought I would be able to retrieve it with find_element_by_xpath("")_  Presumably you have an actual value in there, instead of empty quotes.  How did you get the xpath value you're using?  Did you use the browser right-click inspect element feature?

Comment: Yeah, inspect > right click > copy xpath. But when I print it out I just get random info

Comment: You haven't given us enough detail to provide an actual answer. You haven't shown us the actual html structure, or the code you're using to retrieve the value, or the output you're getting.  All I can say is "You must have done something wrong", but I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input").get_attribute('value')
```